# What does the F number in a lens name mean?

Tags: lens, aperture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the f-stop printed on the lens refer to?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/what-does-the-f-stop-printed-on-the-lens-refer-to)

I understand that for a DSLR you can modify the aperture(the F number) to allow more or less light to enter the camera.

But than what does F2.8 in "Sigma 10mm/F2.8 EX DC Fisheye HSM compatible Canon " mean?
How does the F number of lens compare with the F number of DSLR?

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3262

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are mistaken on the first point, changing F-number on the DSLR only instructs the **lens** to open/close the iris (aperture) to let more or less light in. Nothing changes on the DSLR, except that the metering calculations take the new f number into account.

F/2.8 on the lens means the **maximum** size of the opening is the focal length divided by 2.8, although how much light the lens lets in is a function of the f-number alone (i.e. two f/2.8 lenses with different focal lengths will let in the same amount of light).

See also

- [What is aperture, and how does it affect my photographs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-is-aperture-and-how-does-it-affect-my-photograph)
- [What does f-stop mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/594/what-does-f-stop-mean)