# Photo Competition 2019-12: 'Tis the season for a fresh start

Tags: photo-competition

#### Theme

This is an attempt to kickstart a new photo competition here on Photo-SE.

Seeing as it's already halfway through December and approaching the new year/decade, the concept of the theme combines the winter season with the idea of fresh starts. Give us your best seasonal photo, or your favorite new beginning. Bonus points for new starts with a seasonal flair!

#### Voting Rules

- Vote up as many images as you like.
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote.
- **Voting closes on December 30, 2019 at 12:00 AM UTC**. The winner will chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo per answer. Multiple entries are encouraged, but please don't spam answers. The aim is quality over quantity.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date.**
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

- Suggest a theme for the next contest. Leave a single comment below in the format,

  > Theme: <*one sentence description*>
- Upvote the comment(s) with the theme you would like to see next month.

Good luck!

Comment: It's mid-summer in half the world.

Comment: One link to this competition will be helpful :)

Comment: Almost 90% of the world's population lives in the northern half. I think we can have a winter theme without leaving out the rest — if you live in a part of the world where the season is different, feel free to turn the theme upside down with your entry!

Comment: @RomeoNinov What link? The contest is *here*.

Comment: Prizes? I think Scott will award the top-voted entry a shiny green checkmark. :)

Comment: @PeterTaylor That occurred to me. Echoing mattdm's comment, I hope that a southern hemisphere resident adds a nice twist on the concept.

Comment: Compulsory antipodean seasonal link to [Tim Minchin's "White Wine in the Sun"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCNvZqpa-7Q). If that doesn't make you shed a tear, you have no heart.

Comment: **Theme:** New Years Resolution...Not Going to Plan

Comment: Theme proposal: _Portraits by Candlelight_ (inspired by [Is it practical to shoot portraits by only candlelight?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/17116/1943).

Comment: Theme: _After the party's over._

Comment: More interpretive theme suggestion: Dichotomy

Comment: @mattdm in case I forget, message me to run the next bounty on this after yours expires. Keep this thing going strong through the month. Thanks!

Comment: Suggested theme - "Something Different". things that most people don't usually take pictures of. Not obscene or gross, just something besides sunsets, vistas, pretty women, babies, etc. Tasteful, artistic, and atypical of the usual stuff.

Comment: What is the question here ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan well, I suppose this is an around-the-horn attempt to answer-by-asking-the-counterexample the Meta-PSE question [Is the Photo-SE community effectively dead?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7002/is-the-photo-se-community-effectively-dead) Really, it's just an attempt to kickstart a sense of participation and interesting _photographic interest_ in a community whose **name** is Photography.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Location: Iceland on a waterfall that I still can't pronounce

Subject: Life changing goodness and definitely new beginnings.

Date: December 2017

*(Image shrunk down, click to expand)*

[image]

And here's why it was life changing goodness. Please ignore this bit o' context for the contest:

[image]

Comment: awww. The context _really_ ties the dual themes together!

Comment: Also, thank you for posting the first submission to the new contest!

Answer (score 6):

A lone pelican cruising far off the coast of Newport getting a bird's eye view of a December sunset behind Catalina Island - Newport Beach, California, Mid-December, 2019

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Into the woods** -- fresh snow for a new day!

February 2019, Vermont, USA.

[image]

Comment: Bright and gorgeous. Love it!

Comment: It was fun to take and fun to ski.  I have another that I took my next run that's the same, only my own ski tracks go through it.

Answer (score 4):

Location: Howth, near Dublin, Ireland

Subject: Leaving my old life behind and starting anew. I got divorced this year, sold my house, packed my stuff and moved to Dublin. Left the life that I built up the last decade to start anew in a different place.

Date: 15/12/2019

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Garden Bench Rebirth** - Taken Feb 2013 at my uncle's house in Stanly County, NC after a snowfall. A bit of winter with spring right on the doorstep.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Location: Austin, Texas, USA

Subject: [Montopolis Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montopolis_Bridge), after having spent more than 80 years as a vehicular bridge and important river crossing, was recently closed to vehicles and now has a fresh start as a bridge for pedestrians and bicyclists.

Date: June 2019

[image]

Taken on Ilford HP5 Plus 400 black-and-white film, pushed to 800.

Answer (score 2):

**Location**: CocoCay

**Date**: December 2019

[image]

---

```
Make                            : FUJIFILM
Camera Model Name               : X-T20
Exposure Time                   : 1/2000
F Number                        : 4.5
Exposure Program                : Shutter speed priority AE
ISO                             : 400
Create Date                     : 2019:12:25 17:22:32
Shutter Speed Value             : 1/2048
Aperture Value                  : 4.4
Brightness Value                : 8.97
Exposure Compensation           : -0.33
Max Aperture Value              : 3.5
Flash                           : No Flash
Focal Length                    : 67.1 mm
Picture Mode                    : Shutter speed priority AE
Image Size                      : 6000x4000
Megapixels                      : 24.0
Field Of View                   : 20.2 deg
Focal Length                    : 67.1 mm (35 mm equivalent: 101.0 mm)
Hyperfocal Distance             : 50.12 m
```

Comment: Hi Josh, welcome to Photo-SE. Thanks for your submission, it's a beautiful shot! =)

Comment: Not sure if this is allowed but this photo is edited.

Comment: @scottbb Thanks!

Comment: Edits are absolutely allowed. Just as much art occurs in post (or in the darkroom, in the old days) as does in camera.

Comment: @scottbb Awesome! Thanks! Here's the original if anyone is interested: https://i.imgur.com/hMwT8KM.jpg

Comment: Thanks for showing the original. It's nice to see the difference between out of camera (OOC) and post work. Ansel Adams said, "you don’t take a photograph, you make it." He spent more time in the darkroom than he ever did capturing photos, he spent a _lot_ of time capturing (he even missed the births of two sons because he was lugging around a 8x10 camera in the mountains trying to capture his shots).