# Can anyone tell me what camera/lens is in this picture of a Nikon F with 50mm lens?

Tags: nikon

Where would I look on the camera to figure out the specifications of this camera? I've never really owned a camera before.
http://members.accesscable.net/~brent/pics/nikonf.jpg

Comment: It seems like https://www.google.com/search?q=nikon%20f is an obvious place to start!

Comment: The title looks strange as it already answers the question (or part of)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The camera's a late-60s/early-'70s vintage Nikon "F" 35mm SLR with the Photomic FTn 60%-centre-weighted metering prism viewfinder. (The F had interchangeable viewfinder/prism units.)

An advanced camera when it was released, the F was getting a little long in the tooth about the time this version was produced. It does have some rather desirable features, like mirror lock-up and depth-of-field preview, but it can be awkward to wrangle with if you change lenses. (The later AI, or auto-indexing, system brought that "caveman" feature up to date.) It's rugged and reliable, and would make an excellent learner's tool, mostly because it will do nothing at all *for* you. You will want to get the shutter tested and adjusted, though; being a clockwork mechanical shutter, driven by a spring, it will probably be a lot slower than the marked value unless it's been recently adjusted.

The lens is a Nikkor-S 50mm/1.4 Auto "normal" lens. "Auto", in this case, means that the lens can be focused wide open, that it sends some information about the chosen aperture (via a mechanical linkage) to the metering unit in the viewfinder, and that it will stop down automatically to the selected shooting aperture (and then return to wide-open) when the shutter is released. Everything else — focusing, setting the aperture, and indexing the lens to the meter — is manual.

Answer (score 1):

Nikon's Photomic FTn camera and finder coupled with a 50mm f/1.4 lens

See here [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikon_F) for general details about the F Series and see [here](http://www.mir.com.my/michaeliu/cameras/nikonf/ffinders/ftnfinder.htm) for more detailed specs

Comment: My lens actually says 1:3.5 f=13.5 cm, what does does that mean?

Comment: @Tony - That means it's a 135mm f/3.5 lens. A good, sharp "short telephoto" lens suitable for headshots and portraiture, but rather slow.

Comment: Why is it slow?

Comment: @Tony see: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13619/what-is-a-fast-lens?rq=1