# How can I use aperture to make my pictures better?

Tags: aperture, effect, ideas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is aperture, and how does it affect my photographs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-is-aperture-and-how-does-it-affect-my-photographs)

I've recently started trying to change the aperture level on my camera to get cool effects, and I would like to know how I can use aperture to my advantage?

Comment: A better question would be to find an effect you want to replicate and ask how to achieve that.

Comment: What camera do you have?

Comment: The "How does aperture affect my photographs?" part of the earlier question really should help you think about the effects of aperture, which should in turn suggest things you can do to make your pictures better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are fairly new and just starting, so I think it's better to go with simple things first. One important thing you should know first is the value you increase or decrease in your camera to control the aperture is called F value and this is inversely proportional to aperture. The less the F value = More the aperture, More the F value, less the aperture.

By playing with aperture

1. You can make your subject look more popped and separate from the subject. More the aperture (decreased the f value), more the background is blurred.
2. You can make your subject sharp by decreasing the aperture (increasing the f value), most lenses have a sweet point but for now just keep in mind that keeping your f value 5.6-9 should do that.
3. Increasing the aperture (decreasing the f value) will help you take photos easily where the light is low.

That's mainly it

Comment: What do you mean, 'fairly new and just starting'?

Comment: I like your answer.