# Example of desired look: how do I duplicate it?

Tags: lens, aperture, blur

A few questions:

1. In the attached picture if you zoom in, there is a very slight blur on this mans freckles. It is still in focus, but it almost looks as if the picture was painted. How was that effect achieved?
2. If this is a Photoshop effect, what effect is it?
3. What type of lens was most likely used?

The background is very blurred and the subject is very close up. What settings and/or lens would be best for that?

[image]

Comment: I suggest reading this: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-is-aperture-and-how-does-it-affect-my-photographs
There isn't a magic button to make pictures look like those on instagram.

Comment: 1. We can't tell, it's a picture from a phone, not the original. 2. ditto. 3. ditto.

Comment: Despite it being from a phone, any suggestions from experience on what could possibly cause the grainy effect? Or how low the aperture is in numbers?

Comment: Have a read on depth of field and ISO, although i expect that grain is fake rather than noise.

Comment: Re: 1. not ***taken*** on a phone, ***displayed*** on a phone... & we still can't 'zoom in' cos all we have is what you posted, not the original image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the attached picture if you zoom in, there is a very slight blur on this mans freckles. It is still in focus, but it almost looks as if the picture was painted. How was that effect achieved?

Freckles aren't always sharply defined. It may be that that's just how the model looks. There's a fair bit of noise in the photo, and that may be contributing to the "effect" you see; I don't get the impression that it's painted at all, it just looks like a noisy photo to me. JPEG compression may play a role here as well.

> If this is a Photoshop effect, what effect is it?

There's not enough information to know how this image may or may not have been filtered.

> What type of lens was most likely used?

Looks to me like a fairly "normal" lens, i.e. something in the 30-70mm range, depending on the camera sensor size. There's not a lot of obvious distortion. There is, however, plenty of bokeh (blurring) in the background, which suggests a lens with a relatively large aperture.

> The background is very blurred and the subject is very close up. What settings and/or lens would be best for that?

You want a large aperture and a large difference between the camera-to-subject and camera-to-background distances. You could probably take a shot like this with a 50mm lens at f/2 or f/2.8, with the camera fairly close to the subject and plenty of space between the subject and the background.

> Despite it being from a phone, any suggestions from experience on what could possibly cause the grainy effect? Or how low the aperture is in numbers?

Smartphone cameras like those found in an iPhone usually have a fixed aperture around f/2. The grainy effect may be due to compression, or there may not have been a lot of available light, causing the phone to adjust sensitivity upward and resulting in a noisy image.

Comment: Re: 'normal lens' - I'm really not sure how you could tell if it was a stone wall 20ft away @ 135mm or a cliff face 50 yds away @ 50mm, with so little other information... [I'd also be truly amazed if the photo was actually taken on a phone]

Comment: @Tetsujin I based my guess on the amount of depth of field. Because a long lens puts the camera farther from the subject (for equivalent subject framing), you get more depth of field at the same aperture. But there's very little DoF apparent here -- the model's hood goes out of focus just a few inches behind the face.

Comment: @Caleb - I would definitely go for your experience over my 'gut feel' here. My gut feel would be it was 50-70mm f5-ish, APS or cropped after, 'cliff face at 50 yds'...  but that's all it is... 'gut feel'. I'm not a pro & am *more* than happy to be corrected when I get it wrong [though I provide my 'gut feel' details to see how far out I may actually be ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm not a pro either, but I think your estimation isn't too far from mine.